# Problema con foreach dentro de un async await

Tags: javascript, fetch, async-await

Estoy teniendo un problema estoy llamando a mi funcion `getPokemons` que trae información de una api, mi problema es que quiero hacer un array que al finalizar la segunda función `createPokemons` me retorne el arreglo generado. Pero no lo hace.

```
const getPokemons = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=20');
    const data = await res.json();

    function createPokemon(results) {
      const pkArray = []; // Retornar este arreglo.

      results.forEach(async (pokemon) => {
        const pokeRes = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon.name}`);
        const pokeData = await pokeRes.json();

        pkArray.push(pokeData);
      });
      
      return pkArray;
    }

    const pkData = createPokemon(data.results);
    console.log(pkData) // [];
  };
```

Comment: Que interesante, parece que el `push` se esta quedando en el `scope` de la callback de `forEach`, pues es una promesa `async/await`. El problema sería cómo sacar esa operación de ahí. Saludos

Comment: Funfact, copie tu código de ejemplo tal cual y lo probé en la consola de Chrome y me respondió, no sé si se pueda deber a un tema de latencia o de plano la petición no está siendo manejada de manera adecuada. Saludos

Comment: @MartinManriquez, es muy probable que el navegador te esté *trolleando*, sucede a menudo. El motor de JS del navegador no tiene el mismo comportamiento que puedes esperar del motor de Nodejs o de Firefox. Cada motor se comporta *diferente*, sobre todo en temas asíncronos.

Comment: En todo caso, para realizar operaciones asíncronas con iterables, existe el método [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cambia el `forEach` por un `for`

```
 for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        const pokeRes = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon.name}`);
        const pokeData = await pokeRes.json();
        pkArray.push(pokeData);
    }
```

La razón: el `forEach` ejecutará una función asíncrona para cada elemento del arreglo lo que hace más difícil hacer la espera con `async/await`. En cambio el `for` se ejecutará de forma secuencial haciendo la espera correspondiente a cada petición.

---

Quedaría así:

```
const getPokemons = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=20');
    const data = await res.json();

    async function createPokemon(results) {
        const pkArray = []; // Retornar este arreglo.

        for (let i = 0; i < results.lenght; i++) {
            const pokeRes = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon.name}`);
            const pokeData = await pokeRes.json();

            pkArray.push(pokeData);
        }

        return pkArray;
    }

    const pkData = await createPokemon(data.results);
    console.log(pkData) // [];
};
```

Comment: Entonces debemos evitar el uso de `forEach` en operaciones asincrónicas, parece un patrón complicado, saludos