# No puedo acceder a los elementos en mi array de objetos

Tags: javascript, array

Creé esta función donde obtengo datos de los pokemones, cada uno en un objeto por separado, los guardo en un array, pero luego no puedo accederlos.

```
export function obtenerDatosPokemonesPagina (datosPaginador) {
  const datosPokemones = []
  datosPaginador.results.forEach((elemento) => {
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${elemento.name}/`)
      .then((respuesta) => respuesta.json())
      .then((respuesta) => datosPokemones.push(respuesta))
      .catch((error) => (error))
  })
  return datosPokemones
}


const datosPaginador = await obtenerDatosPaginador()
const datosPokemonesPagina = obtenerDatosPokemonesPagina(datosPaginador)

actualizarPagina(datosPaginador, datosPokemonesPagina)
```

Cuando quiero acceder a datos pokemones desde actualizar página, por ejemplo, `datosPokemonesPagina[0]`, me retorna `undefined`, ¿por qué será?

Gracias.

Comment: Agrega un `console.log(respuesta)` antes del `respuesta.json()`, recuerda utilizar los `{ }`

Comment: Hola Lucas. El método `fetch` realiza una llamada asíncrona, quiere decir que la funcion `obtenerDatosPokemonesPagina` debería esperar a obtener las respuestas. Como no lo estas haciendo, siempre va a devolver un arreglo vacío. Te recomiendo revisar [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/480163/16597)